# how to disable check constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl, check-constraints

I have below table with check constraint for salary column. I want to disable the check constraint temporarily. How to disable and enable the check constraints?

```
CREATE TABLE "Employee_Salary_Details"(
  empno int,
  ename varchar(100),
  sal numeric CONSTRAINT CK_SAL CHECK(sal>3500)
)

INSERT INTO "Employee_Salary_Details" VALUES(101,'RAM',200);

ALTER TABLE "Employee_Salary_Details" DISABLE  CONSTRAINT CK_SAL
```

I tried, but it is showing an error message. Is it possible to disable and enable heck constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it possible to disable and enable check constraints?*

No, that's not possible. You need to drop and re-create it.

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee_Salary_Details DROP CONSTRAINT CK_SAL;
```

Do your business, and then add it back:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee_Salary_Details ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SAL CHECK (sal > 3500);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way around..

```
SELECT consrc,con.*
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = 'public' and contype='c'
```

Try to find your constraint in this query result..
And then update '**conrelid**' to **0** for that entry.

This will disable that constraint.

Hope this works..

And after your insertion work done.. Revert same value for '**conrelid**'

Comment: Suggesting to manipulate the system tables directly is a really bad advice

Comment: Yeah.. But this is one of the solution for this problem.
I'm just giving another approach.